# Find all text in HTML web scrape after a specific string (python3)

Tags: html, regex, python-3.x, web-scraping

I have scraped a website in order to find trending TV shows.

my html output looks something like this (obviously much longer but for brevitys sake):

```
<span class="btn-utility-container"><a class="btn-utility btn-watchlist " 
data-button="watchlist" data-id="299830" data-name="American Pickers"
```

I want to find and then extract the data that comes after **data-name="** and then ends with the next **"**

so in this case, the output would be:  **American Pickers** (no quotations)

For reference, here is my code that does not work

```
wikis = ["http://www.tvguide.com/trending-tonight/"]
for wiki in wikis:
    website = requests.get(wiki)
    caps = re.findall(b'data-name=">(.|\n)*?<\/">', website.content) #Relevant line
```

Comment: What are you doing with `soup`? It isn't used

Comment: Apologies, was playing around with different code and I left it in -- removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the name of the show in `data-name`, then you grab it like this.

```
caps = re.findall(b'data-name="(.*?)"', website.content)
```

Or this if you are not a fan of dot-star

```
caps = re.findall(b'data-name="([^"]*?)"', website.content)
```

Comment: absolutely works so thank you!   is there a way to remove the 'b (byte) attached to each title in the output?

Comment: Great! Maybe remove the `b` in front of the `'data-name=...'`? I left it in because that was in your initial code.

Comment: figured it out: y = [x.decode('utf-8') for x in caps]